# Enter a command for a user

Tags: zsh

I have written a ZSH function whose output is a command line which runs a program I need the user to be able to interact with.

At the moment I just echo the command line and instruct the user to copy-paste it so that they have the necessary access to its pipes, however is there a way I can just have the function finish by entering the command for the user as if they had copied and pasted it themselves?

I have looked into using zle but that seems to require a key binding, whereas I just want the user to be able to run: `myzshfunction arg1` and the ultimate result to be their terminal attached to the program launched as a result of some processing of their `arg1`.

```
$ myzshfunction arg2*2
Run this command! foobar baz4
$ foobar baz4
  ...
```

The function looks something like this:

```
myzshfunction() {
  if [[ $# = 0 ]]
  then
    echo "usage: myzshfunction 1.2.3.4"
    return
  fi

  local creds=`curl "https://xxx/$1/latest" | jq -r 'x'`
  local cred_arr=("${(@s|/|)creds}")
  local pwd_pipe=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo $pwd_pipe
  exec 3<>$pwd_pipe
  rm $pwd_pipe
  echo $cred_arr[2] >&3
  echo "Run this: sshpass -d3 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null "$cred_arr[1]@$1"
  exec 3>&-
}
```

TIA

Comment: Can you share the code of your function? Or maybe it's some kind of corporate secret?

Comment: I have added a redacted version of the function

Comment: Ah, interesting. Excuse me for accidental rudeness. I saw something similar in [password-store](https://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about). It uses `xclip` to [copy passwords into clipboard](https://github.com/stuartsierra/password-store/blob/master/src/password-store.sh). Maybe you it can be suitable for your needs?

Comment: Backing up a little, why does the user need to modify the given command line before executing it?

Comment: @chepner The user gives some input (an IP address they want to SSH into), the script fetches the creds in order to login to that host and then I want to automatically drop the user directly into an SSH session with that host

Comment: Oh, then you don't need to do anything. `ssh` won't exit until you exit from the remote shell, blocking your `zsh` function from completing until that time.

Comment: That said, getting a username and password from an HTTP service seems ... less than ideal from a security standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Use `print -z` to add text to the buffer. From the documentation:

```
-z     Push the arguments onto the editing buffer stack, separated by spaces.
```

Calling `foo`, defined below, will result in `hi` being placed on the command line as if the user had typed it. For example,

```
% foo () { print -z hi; }
% foo
% hi
```

Comment: This is close to what I want, although it isn't compatible with the anonymous pipe method of passing a password because that fd remains belonging I assume to the previously running command.

Comment: You could just leave file descriptor 3 open when the function exits, but yes, it would be better to use a `zle` widget to let you edit and execute the command line first. (Looking for it, hang on....)

Comment: Update: never did find the command. I though there was something similar to `vared`, but for commands. I might be thinking of `fc`, which isn't entirely appropriate here, as you would first have to populate the history with the desired command. (Doable, but somewhat verbose.)

Comment: I have implemented this using zle but it's kinda gross using a bindkey sequence rather than just being able to enter my original command, hit return and then have magic happen

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I could come up with was to use `zle` - the `Zsh Line Editor`.

This lets you update the command the user is currently editing, which to me feels a bit hacky. I would prefer a solution that lets you call a function, hit return, and then cleanly run a function with STDIO attached to your terminal as if you had run the resulting command line.

Perhaps you could emulate this by bindkey'ing the return key and doing some sort of decision/routing from there to see if the user wants to call `myfunc`. For now, my solution requires the <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> sequence is entered after typing a target for `$host`.

```
zle-myfunc() {
  apikey=$(keychain-environment-variable api-key)
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Add your api-key to the keychain: "
    BUFFER='security add-generic-password -U -a ${USER} -D "environment variable" -s "api-key" -w'
    zle accept-line
    return 1
  fi
  local host=$BUFFER
  zle kill-buffer
  local creds=`curl ..." | jq -r ...`
  if [ -z creds ]; then
    echo "Couldn't get creds, check your network"
    return 1
  fi
  local creds_arr=("${(@s|/|)creds}")
  local pwd_pipe=$(mktemp -u)
  mkfifo $pwd_pipe
  exec 3<>$pwd_pipe
  # anonymise the pipe
  rm $pwd_pipe
  echo "$creds_arr[2]" >&3
  BUFFER="sshpass -d3 ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $creds_arr[1]@$host"
  zle accept-line
  # exec 3>&-
}
zle -N zle-myfunc
bindkey '\ei' zle-myfunc
```